# how to find who locks who in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2005 SP3.  From Activity monitor, I notice a lot of processors were locked in suspended mode.  do you know how to find who locks my processes?

Answer (score 7):

`exec sp_who`

will tell you what processes are blocked by what other processes.  You can also use

```
exec sp_lock
```

to see what's being locked by said blocking process.

Comment: For details on who's who in the blocking game, read the description of the `blk` column in `sp_who`'s result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx

Comment: Calling "DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid)" with the spid you get back from sp_who will also show the last sql statement that the process ran.

Comment: SP_WHO2 provides more real world useful information than sp_who and sp_lock,  DBCC INPUTBUFFER(SPID) is a must have to go with SP_WHO2 to see what query they are running.

Answer (score 4):

SP_WHO2

SP_WHO2 shows blocking and blocked by spids along with host names and much more useful information needed to track down the source.

Edit:  Also if the output list is long try SP_WHO2 'active'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ralph's excellent post, [here's](http://blogs.technet.com/rob/archive/2008/05/26/detecting-sql-server-2005-blocking.aspx) a good article on the various methods available to you to monitor blocking - it's by one of Microsoft's Premier Field Engineers.